# Bind button enabled property to combobox selected item

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

A while back i had read a tutorial on data binding (maybe it was MVVM?) in Windows Forms. I've sense forgot everything and forgot the name of the tutorial.

What i would like to do is bind the enabled property of a button to a combox's selected item.

Logic: If combobox has selected item- enable button.
       else disable button.

I'm aware of the combobox_textchanged and combobox_selecteditemchanged event and i would like to avoid using it if possible.

Answer (score 0):

In WPF / MVVM, this is a UI issue that can be handled in a ViewModel class. In Windows Forms, you might also want to create a ViewModel class separate from your model class to keep UI concerns away from the Model classes. Either way, you can create a Boolean property like "IsActiveCustomer", or whatever it is in your case, in the object class you are binding to. Your property could either have a getter that returns a value based on the *property* that is bound to the combo box -- or you could use the combo box selected index changed or selected value changed events and set the Boolean property accordingly. Then, of course, bind the Enabled property of the button to the Boolean property. Probably need to know what you are data binding to in order to provide specifics (binding to object vs. BindingSource/table adapter, etc.)

Comment: You wouldn't happen to have an example of this would you?